# The maximum value of a byte

Tags: java, byte

I am confused why maximum value of a byte is equal to 127. From my understanding, the the maximum of a byte (8 bits) should be 2 to the power of 0 plus 2 to the power of 1 to 2 to the power of 7?

Comment: `byte` is signed in Java. -128 to +127.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Alright, it is signed! That's why!

Comment: All the primitive types are signed except `boolean` and `char`